# lining two objects up

Tags: transforms, workflow, snapping

I have two 3D scans of a tunnel that I made [polycam](https://poly.cam/). The tunnel has two corridors that run parallel to one another. The problem is that I can't get them to run parallel to one another in blender. Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

I'm sure apps like polycam aren't 100% perfect and maybe that's what's going on here but I'm also wondering if there's something I could be differently in Blender to make this work better?

The models I'm using can be found here:

https://terrafrost.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/Sep25,2-41PM-poly.glb
https://terrafrost.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/Sep25,3-03PM-poly.glb

Any ideas?